# Azure App Service Plan | Scale up/ Scale out grayed

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

[App Plan Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXc5N.png)

[App Plan Price Tier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adDUX.png)

We need to scale up the app service plan for already deployed function app. But Scale up option is disabled in Azure portal ? Please any one have experience on this

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you have an `Y1` App Service Plan which is a so-called **Consumption plan**:

> Scale automatically and only pay for compute resources when your
> functions are running.
> On the Consumption plan, instances of the Functions host are dynamically added and removed based on the number of incoming events.

Source: [Overview of plans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203#overview-of-plans)

So you can't scale your Consumption plan because it scales automatically. You might consider switching to a dedicated plan (See: [Dedicated hosting plans for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dedicated-plan?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203))

Comment: Martin Brandl Thank you very much. This is save my time.